# Save assert stack trace to a file

Tags: android, logging, junit, assert

I have an Android Test Application in which I run several tests.
I use various assert calls such as assertEquals, assertTrue, assertNull and so on. When such an assert fails, I wish to save the stack trace to a file on the device. Does such a thing already exist or do you have any tips on how I could implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just catch `AssertionError`

```
try {
    assertEquals(true, true);

} catch (AssertionError ex) {
    // code that write exception to file
}
```

Or more advanced you can use [acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) and implement your own `ReportSender`.